# Terraform download current infastructure into tf file

Tags: terraform

I am migrating some manually provisioned infastructure over to terraform.

Currently I am manually defining the terraform resource's in `.tf` files, importing the remote state with `terraform import`. I then run `terraform plan` multiple times, each time modifying the local `tf` files until the match the existing infastructure.

How can I speed this process up by downloading the remote state directly into a `.tf` resource file?

Comment: If you do not care about best practices then you can use Google's `terraformer`. Otherwise, this is the general procedure.

Comment: What resources? AWS, azure, ...?

Answer (score 0):

The mapping from the configuration as written in `.tf` files to real infrastructure that's indirectly represented in state snapshots is a lossy one.

A typical Terraform configuration has arguments of one resource derived from attributes of another, uses `count` or `for_each` to systematically declare multiple similar objects, and might use Terraform modules to decompose the problem and reuse certain components.

All of that context is lost in the mapping to real remote objects, and so there is no way to recover it and generate idiomatic `.tf` files that would be ready to use. Therefore you would always need to make *some* modifications to the configuration in order to produce a useful Terraform configuration.

While keeping that caveat in mind, you *can* review the settings for objects you've added using `terraform import` by running the `terraform show` command. Its output is intended to be read by humans rather than machines, but it does present the information using a Terraform-language-*like* formatting, and so what it produces can potentially be a starting point for a Terraform configuration, with the caveat that it won't always be totally valid and will typically need at least *some* adjustments in order to be accepted by `terraform plan` as valid, and to be useful for ongoing use.